# initial selected searchbar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` from a Search Display Controller and want the `UISearchBar` to be selected when the view is Loaded.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

in your `viewDidAppear` method
and when the user pushes the "search button", call

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

and begin your search algorithm.

Comment: hey phix i thought of that too but I can't call the searchBar since it came with the Search Display Controller
I edited my first post to be more specific

Comment: What about [searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder] ?

Answer (score 1):

Call the method `becomeFirstResponder` on the search bar.

`[searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` will programmatically select the search bar. See the UIResponder docs for more details on this.